# Podio Create Item rate limit after 25 calls

Tags: podio

I have to create items in podio using the api. When i let my program go full speed i noticed that after 5 - 6 items I get an error response from podio saying:

```
{  
   "error_propagate":false,
   "error":"rate_limit",
   "error_description":"You have hit the rate limit. Please wait 300 seconds before trying again",
   "request":{  
      "url":"http://api.podio.com/oauth/token",
      "query_string":"",
      "method":"POST"
   }
}
```

I tought the rate limit was 5000 calls/H and I get this error after 25 calls...

I added a thread.sleep in my code, and now it seems to be better, but even when I let the thread sleep for 10s I still get this error, I have now set the thread.sleep to 20 sec and it seems to work.

Is there a hidden rate limit to the number off calls per second ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using Username password authentication here. The token request endpoint have lower limit from my experience. So the best way to solve this is to store and reuse the access tokens, instead of re-authenticating every time your program runs.

Podio API client libraries provide convenience methods to do this. See this links:

- http://podio.github.io/podio-dotnet/sessions/
- http://podio.github.io/podio-php/sessions

Answer (score 1):

The rate limit is 1000 calls/H. so you can put sleep accordingly.